# Nightmare: Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I've started experimenting around with Nightmare and mocha to perform automated tests. I am getting the error below, despite following the instruction in the error itself.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

var url = 'http://www.google.com/'

describe('Page availability', function() {
  it('Should open homepage', function(done) {
    var nightmare = Nightmare();

    nightmare
      .goto(url)
      .wait('body')
      .evaluate(function () {
        return document.querySelector('.gb_P').innerHTML
      })
      .end()
      .then(function(text) {
        expect(text).to.equal('images');
        done();
      })
  });
});
```

when running the above script with `mocha test.js', this is the output that I get:

```
Page availability
    1) Should open homepage


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Page availability Should open homepage:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

**Confession:** I am not (yet) versed with promises, but I don't quite get why Mocha isn't accounting for the **done** callback that I've provided inside then.

Comment: Oh, when I was reading the title in the questions overview, I thought that you had a _nightmare_ ... but it's just a library.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the default time out for Mocha is 2 seconds, and your Nightmare actions are likely taking longer than that to complete.  (Google takes notoriously long to finish loading.)

Inside of the `describe` or `it`, you could set `this.timeout(ms)`, or use `--timeout [ms]` when running the mocha command.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this exact same problem for hours, finally found a solution that works!

First and foremost @Ross is correct here, and while 2 seconds *can* be enough, it is not **always** going to be enough time to wait for google, or any other page for that matter. For this reason I bumped my timeout up to 15000ms, a safe bet, maybe over kill, but unless you have a really slow internet connection, you'll be safe.

Secondly, I have found that

```
querySelector(selector).innerHTML
```

often returns null. This may be due to the fact that there is a large amount of human error involved in writing a selector path, or some other technical issue happening behind the scenes with either javascript or nightmare's `.evaluate()` function.

It is worth mentioning that the problem does not seem to originate from the `wait()` function, as I have found that the framework is perfectly happy using the same query selector, but swapping the `innerHTML` property for the `length` property.

Example:

This will result in a timeout error, in addition to `.evaluate()` returning null:

```
.wait("body > div.wrap > h1")
   .evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelectorAll("body > div.wrap > h1").innerHTML;
    })
```

whereas changing innerHTML to length will pass perfectly fine

```
.wait("body > div.wrap > h1")
   .evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelectorAll("body > div.wrap > h1").length;
    })
```

I am not confident why this is, however, these are my findings.

Thusly, in order to resolve OP's issue I used `document.getElementsByClassName()` which has proven to me a far easier and/or accurate method for obtaining DOM elements

re-writing OP's code as such:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

var url = 'http://www.google.com/'

describe('Page availability', function() {
    this.timeout(15000);
    it('Should open homepage', function(done) {
        var nightmare = Nightmare();

        nightmare
        .goto(url)
        .wait('body')
        .evaluate(function () {
            var headerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("gb_P");
            return headerDiv[1].innerHTML
        })
        .end()
        .then(function(text) {
            expect(text).to.equal('Images');
            done();
        })
    });
});
```

Yields a Passing test.

Further, OP has forgotten to capitalize 'Images' which is the innerHTML of that class.

**In conclusion**,

I am not `querySelector(selector).innerHTML` can still work, however, for targeting specific classes and id's `getElementById()` is a safer choice. They can work in tandem too, for example the following code runs with out errors for me, where as jamming the whole query selector in `querySelector(selector).innerHTML` crashes the test.

```
.wait("body > div#wpwrap > div#wpcontent > div#wpbody > div#wpbody-content > div.wrap > h1")
    .evaluate(() => {
        var headerDiv = document.getElementById("wpbody-content");
        h1Html = headerDiv.querySelector(".wrap h1").innerHTML;
        return h1Html;
    })
```